# meaning of piping value of array to filter:$select.search in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking at angular code that uses ui-select.  In every case the same syntax is used for th ui-select-choice value, which looks something like this:

```
<ui-select-choice repeat="value in array | filter:$select.search">
    <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(value.name | highlight:$select.search))">
 </ui-select-choice>
```

I understand that the values are being sent to a filter, but I don't know what $select.search is, so I don't know what the filter actually does.  I also don't know what the trustAsHtml does, but I haven't researched it too closely so it's not as important to get an explanation.

can anyone give me an explanation of how this logic works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui-select lets you do a search. That search value binds to `$select.search`, so your array is filtered by your search criteria.

`trustAsHtml` is part of the service `$sce` which lets angular trust an html string, which can be inseted then to your html with `ng-bind-html`.